# Thinkpad T40 w/ XP+SP2 keeps dropping off wifi

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, thinkpad, wifi-driver

I have a Thinkpad T40 laptop with XP / SP2. Its been locked up for the last 2 yrs or so as the screen stopped working. I took it out and plugged it to my TV and it boots up fine. But the wifi connection is intermittent - keeps dropping off every 1-2 minutes. Does anyone know what I cn do to diagnose the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the power saving settings for wi-fi (either on the laptop or on the base station).  I've had the same exact problem with my Thinkpad.  When it throttles back to save power, it loses the ability to sync with the access point.

Comment: Where can I find the power savings settings for "wi fi"? Also, this is happening when I am plugged in to the wall with the battery taken out!

Comment: The settings are in the device manager screen for the hardware itself.  You won't see them in either the Windows or ThinkPad specific power managers.  Doesn't matter if it's on battery or A/C, those device specific power saving parameters are always in effect.